# Visual studio 2022 crashes when choosing toolbox items

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I have installed visual studio 2022 and when I try to choose items from the toolbox it gives me an error and closes the visual.

The errors that show me in the event viewer are:

1.Application: devenv.exe
Framework version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process terminated due to an internal error in the .NET runtime at IP address 00007FFA2C39BC04 (00007FFA2BF80000) with exit code 80131506.

2.Faulting Application Name: devenv.exe, Version: 17.6.33829.357, Time Stamp: 0x649e1133
Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.8.9167.0, timestamp: 0x648f6bcc
Exception Code: 0xc0000005
Error Offset: 0x000000000041bc04
Faulting process identifier: 0x2178
Faulting Application Start Time: 0x01d9b5609da2915b
Faulting Application Path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Report Identifier: 6f8cce26-0af0-4979-97b1-aacab821d821
Full name of the package with errors:
Relative application identifier of the faulty package:

I have tried to repair visual studio, I have also uninstalled and reinstalled it but it still doesn't work

Comment: Hello, I have updated Visual Studio to version 17.9 and now it does not close when I open the tool launcher but in the 'Universal Windows Components' and 'WPF Components' tabs I get the following error:
Tab filling failed due to an exception. If this assembly is loaded, a different permission set will be generated from other instances. (Exception from HRESULT:0x80131401)